# Generally true or false? $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(g(n)) \ne f(\lim_{n\to\infty} g(n)) $

Tags: probability-theory, limits

I came across a proof in a probability textbook proof for the proposition 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} P(E_n) = P(\lim_{n\to\infty}  E_n) $$

which prompts me to ask, (why) is the following generally true or false?
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(g(n)) = f(\lim_{n\to\infty}  g(n)) $$

Although the mere presence of the proof already implies "false", could someone explain why the $\lim$ is not necessarily associative with respect to functions?

Comment: You're in trouble if the limit of $g(n)$ doesn't exist. You're also in trouble if $f$ is not continuous. Why not try to construct some examples to illustrate what I've written? Then post them as an answer.

Comment: It's also not entirely clear what you mean by "lim," so it is difficult to compare your first statement with your second. In particular, $\lim E_n$ only makes sense if the sets $E_n$ are nested in some way since they are sets and not numbers, in which case the "limit" is defined to be the infinite union or infinite intersection. Otherwise, there is no measure-theoretically relevant meaning to the symbol "$\lim E_n.$"

Comment: @GerryMyerson I made an attempt and posted an answer.

Comment: @B.Mackey correct. In my haste, I left out the context of the proof. In this case $E_n$ is an increasing sequence of events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\lim_{n\to\infty}g(n)$ does not exist, for example, $g(n) = n $, then $f(\lim_{n\to\infty}g(n))$ cannot be evaluated.

If $f$ is discontinuous at $a$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}g(n) = a$, then $f(\lim_{n\to\infty}g(n))$ does not exist.

Suppose $f(x) = \frac{n}{x} $ and $g(n) = n$. Then $f(\lim_{n\to\infty}g(n))$ gives us  $\frac{n}{\infty})$.

However, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(g(n)) = \frac{\infty}{\infty}=1 $.  Thus by counterexample, it is not generally true that $f(\lim_{n\to\infty}g(n)) = \lim_{n\to\infty}f(g(n))$. That is, $f(\lim_{n\to\infty}g(n)) \ne \lim_{n\to\infty}f(g(n))$.

Comment: Your second line is slightly off. If the limit of $g$ is $a$ then $f(lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(g(n))=f(a)$. The problem is that $f(g(n)$ won't necessarily approach $f(a)$.

For instance take $f(x)=1$ if $x>0$ and $0$ otherwise, and take $g(n)=1/n$ then the limits exist both ways, but they are just different.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. I have 
$f(\lim_{n\to\infty}g(n))=f(0)=0$? for one limit, and 

$ \lim_{n\to\infty}f(g(n)) = f(x) = ?$ which I am not sure   of for the other. At which $x$ is $f(x)$ discontinous? I did make a correction though. Maybe you could suggest an edit? But I don't have the rep to accept it.

Comment: Just work through my example $\lim f(g(n))=\lim(f(1/n))=1$ (as $f(1/n)$ is the constant sequence $1$). However $f(\lim(g(n))=f(\lim(1/n))=f(0)=0$.

Comment: Ah you've edited your comment.

Well just look at the sequence $f(g(n))$, as $g(n)=1/n$ which is positive then $f(g(n))=f(1/n)=1$ for all $n$. Hence this sequence is constant with value 1 and its limit is 1.

Comment: $ \lim_{n\to\infty}f(g(n)) = 1$. I see now... $f(\lim_{n\to\infty}g(n)) \ne \lim_{n\to\infty}f(g(n))$ is indeed what I am attempting to show.

Comment: @hardbutfun Hello, you have set a bounty on another question but you did not really explain what you want.